# i am getting a key error when trying to pull a row from an array, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, mnist, keyerror

i am following some code from a book:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version = 1)
print(mnist.keys())

X = mnist["data"]
y = mnist["target"]
some_digit = X[0]
some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28,28)

plt.imshow(some_digit_image,cmap="binary")
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

The error is coming from `some_digit = X[0]`
"in get_loc raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 0"

does anyone know why its giving me this error?

Comment: can you `print(X)`?

Comment: Check the type of X variable. It is not a list I guess.

Comment: `mnist.keys()` ==> if that works, `mnist` is a dictionary. There is no key `0` (integer) in your dict. Maybe it is `"0"` (string) - you are printing them , so you should be able to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the `mnist` dataset as:

```
X, y = fetch_openml("mnist_784", version=1, return_X_y=True, as_frame=False)
```

The `return_X_y=True` parameter will directly returns `(data, target)` instead of a Bunch object, as mentioned in the `fetch_openml` documentation.

Comment: this solved my issue thank you.

Comment: you welcome! Accept the answer if you have not other problem about this!